# Left join data frames by group and interval

Tags: r, fuzzyjoin

I need to `interval_left_join` two dataframes by groups (the grouping variable is `File`), but using this code I get this error:

```
  library(BiocManager)
  library(fuzzyjoin)
  df1 %>%
    group_by(File) %>%
    interval_left_join(.,
                       df2,
                       by = c("Endtime_ms", "Starttime_ms"))
Error in .width_as_unnamed_integer(width, msg = "an end that is greater or equal to its start minus one") : 
  each range must have an end that is greater or equal to its start minus one
```

I've checked with:

```
df2 %>% filter((Endtime_ms - Starttime_ms) < 1)
```

but there's no such row. What's wrong here and how can the error be avoided?

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(File = c("F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
                                 "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
                                 "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
                                 "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F16", "F16", "F16", 
                                 "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", 
                                 "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", 
                                 "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16"
  ), Starttime_ms = c(282737L, 285346L, 287201L, 287339L, 288005L, 
                      288909L, 289316L, 289389L, 291943L, 291958L, 291961L, 292298L, 
                      292498L, 292600L, 294446L, 295671L, 297272L, 297794L, 299650L, 
                      300935L, 301832L, 303100L, 303235L, 303586L, 305445L, 307329L, 
                      307540L, 311383L, 311767L, 311826L, 335088L, 335647L, 336490L, 
                      339435L, 339440L, 339445L, 340319L, 343288L, 344880L, 345235L, 
                      347762L, 347958L, 349482L, 350240L, 351592L, 352045L, 352710L, 
                      353223L, 355935L, 357778L, 361413L, 363835L, 365470L, 365671L, 
                      366911L, 367650L, 369424L, 369550L, 369694L, 370864L), Endtime_ms = c(287201, 
                                                                                            287339, 288005, 289316, 288909, 289389, 292498, 291943, 291958, 
                                                                                            292298, 292293, 292600, 294446, 3e+05, 295671, 297272, 297794, 
                                                                                            301321, 303100, 301617, 302120, 303586, 305445, 307329, 307321, 
                                                                                            307540, 311383, 311767, 312054, 314075, 336134, 335930, 338980, 
                                                                                            340319, 339700, 346995, 343288, 345170, 345261, 346111, 352678, 
                                                                                            349008, 350202, 350927, 352024, 352528, 353074, 357252, 359958, 
                                                                                            360286, 364993, 365264, 366411, 366815, 368423, 369127, 370533, 
                                                                                            374517, 370435, 373317), Utterance = c("=[like] no::rmally how it happens so it 's happened <in the> Hauptbahnhof a lot, ", 
                                                                                                                                   "((m: points outward with right thumb, beat on \"Hauptbahnhof\")) ", 
                                                                                                                                   "(0.804)", "((m: both h moving in alternation palm outward)) ", 
                                                                                                                                   "because like tho:s:e  ", "(0.480)", "((m: both h kept palm down at chest height, slight beat on \"train station\")) ", 
                                                                                                                                   "I don 't know if you have ever used that bathroom, in the train station¿= ", 
                                                                                                                                   "(0.015)", "=[no] ", "=[no] ", "(0.302)", "((m: both h palms toward face, alternating movement)) ", 
                                                                                                                                   "it 's (.) ↑!it! is↑ kind o:f: you ha- it 's not intuitive which one 's the mens' which one 's the womens' like you need to really like <read the si:[gn>] ", 
                                                                                                                                   "((m: both h palm to face at neck height first move circularly toward chin then back)) ", 
                                                                                                                                   "((m: both hands, first right then left, rotate around wrist)) ", 
                                                                                                                                   "((m: both h rotate toward face)) ", "((m & h: head moves forward and back while both h palm outward fingers spread first approach face, then form ring like binoculars and move outward)) ", 
                                                                                                                                   "[oh the one] you have to pay to [enter¿ like one] euro [or something] °yeah yeah° ", 
                                                                                                                                   "[yeah =yeah =yeah =yeah]  ", "[!yeah!] ", "(0.486)", "((m: both arms 'open up' moving laterally, then both h flex inward twice)) ", 
                                                                                                                                   "and like IT 'S AN OPEN entrance on either end (.) I get it you go in the wrong end ", 
                                                                                                                                   "((m: both h palms open at chest height, circular movement twice)) ", 
                                                                                                                                   "(0.211)", "u::m (.) I was going in one day and the cleaning woman there !stopp!ed me >she was like<  ", 
                                                                                                                                   "(0.384)", "~er~ ", "((m: left h held laterally at knee height)) ", 
                                                                                                                                   "[oh] yeah [((v: laughs))] ", "[u:m] ", "like (.) he applied, to become a diplomat ", 
                                                                                                                                   "((m: b h grabs r thumb with l h @loct)) ", "[yeah] ", "[!got!] accepted starts with diplomatic (.) schooling like he goes through the whole thing which is [!really! h]ard like I 'm I 'm not even attempting it ", 
                                                                                                                                   "((m: b h grabs r index with l h @loct)) ", "((m: b h open palms facing in @peri)) ", 
                                                                                                                                   "[right] ", "((m: b h open palms points to self @ctct)) ", "RIGHT this is [like to join the foreign] service, [right¿] [I think it takes like] three years [does n't it] °to [do everything°]= ", 
                                                                                                                                   "[cos I think you sh-] ", "[yeah ex]actly= ", "=[yeah] ", "[yeah]= ", 
                                                                                                                                   "=[°yeah°]= ", "=°yeah°= ", "=u:m and then they had a ↑budget↑ cut (.) ≈um oh I mean u:h:≈ ", 
                                                                                                                                   "((m: r h half open palm facing down @uprperi)) ", "the US reaches it's um ", 
                                                                                                                                   "budget deficit, >its maximum budget deficit< °what 's° (.) °what 's that called again?° ", 
                                                                                                                                   "((m: r h silent snapping of fingers @rperi)) ", "((m: r h open palm facing in @erperi)) ", 
                                                                                                                                   "°governmental° ", "((m: r h open palm facing up + away @erperi)) ", 
                                                                                                                                   "tt >I don't know so there 's a government shutdown< ", "the [fiscal cliff] ", 
                                                                                                                                   "[a:nd the !fiscal!] yeah °ye[ah]° (.) and u:h and so as a result all new positions are cut  ", 
                                                                                                                                   "((m: r h points forward w: index and thumb @upct)) ", "((m: r h half open palm facing up index + thumb extended @erperi)) "
                                                                                            )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                        -60L))



  df2 <- structure(list(A = c(2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 
                              2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 
                              2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 
                              2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 
                              2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 
                              2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 
                              2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 
                              2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 
                              2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 
                              2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 
                              2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 
                              2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 2.401, 4.16, 
                              4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 
                              4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 
                              4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 
                              4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.16, 4.152, 
                              4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 
                              4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 
                              4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 
                              4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154, 4.154), Starttime_ms = c(309003, 
                                                                                                        309014, 309015, 309019, 309032, 309036, 309047, 309049, 309053, 
                                                                                                        309065, 309069, 309080, 309082, 309086, 309099, 309103, 309114, 
                                                                                                        309115, 309119, 309132, 309136, 309147, 309149, 309153, 309165, 
                                                                                                        309169, 309180, 309182, 309186, 309199, 309203, 309214, 309215, 
                                                                                                        309219, 309232, 309236, 309247, 309249, 309265, 309280, 309282, 
                                                                                                        309299, 309314, 309315, 309332, 309347, 309349, 309365, 309380, 
                                                                                                        309382, 309399, 309414, 309415, 309432, 309447, 309449, 309465, 
                                                                                                        309480, 309482, 309499, 309514, 309515, 309532, 309547, 309549, 
                                                                                                        309565, 309580, 309582, 309599, 309614, 309615, 309632, 309647, 
                                                                                                        309649, 309665, 309680, 309682, 309699, 309714, 309715, 309732, 
                                                                                                        309747, 309749, 309765, 309780, 309782, 309799, 309814, 309815, 
                                                                                                        309832, 309847, 309849, 309865, 309880, 309882, 309899, 309914, 
                                                                                                        309915, 309932, 309947, 309949, 309965, 309980, 309982, 369502, 
                                                                                                        369505, 369517, 369519, 369522, 369535, 369538, 369551, 369552, 
                                                                                                        369555, 369569, 369572, 369584, 369585, 369588, 369602, 369605, 
                                                                                                        369617, 369619, 369622, 369635, 369638, 369650, 369651, 369652, 
                                                                                                        369655, 369669, 369672, 369683, 369684, 369685, 369688, 369702, 
                                                                                                        369705, 369716, 369717, 369719, 369722, 369735, 369738, 369751, 
                                                                                                        369752, 369755, 369769, 369772, 369784, 369785, 369788, 369802, 
                                                                                                        369805, 369817, 369819, 369822, 369835, 369838, 369850, 369851, 
                                                                                                        369852, 369855, 369869, 369872, 369883, 369884, 369885, 369888, 
                                                                                                        369902, 369905, 369917, 369919, 369922, 369935, 369938, 369951, 
                                                                                                        369952, 369955, 369969, 369972, 369984, 369985), Endtime_ms = c(309014, 
                                                                                                                                                                        309015, 309019, 309032, 309036, 309047, 309049, 309053, 309065, 
                                                                                                                                                                        309069, 309080, 309082, 309086, 309099, 309103, 309114, 309115, 
                                                                                                                                                                        309119, 309132, 309136, 309147, 309149, 309153, 309165, 309169, 
                                                                                                                                                                        309180, 309182, 309186, 309199, 309203, 309214, 309215, 309219, 
                                                                                                                                                                        309232, 309236, 309247, 309249, 309265, 309280, 309282, 309299, 
                                                                                                                                                                        309314, 309315, 309332, 309347, 309349, 309365, 309380, 309382, 
                                                                                                                                                                        309399, 309414, 309415, 309432, 309447, 309449, 309465, 309480, 
                                                                                                                                                                        309482, 309499, 309514, 309515, 309532, 309547, 309549, 309565, 
                                                                                                                                                                        309580, 309582, 309599, 309614, 309615, 309632, 309647, 309649, 
                                                                                                                                                                        309665, 309680, 309682, 309699, 309714, 309715, 309732, 309747, 
                                                                                                                                                                        309749, 309765, 309780, 309782, 309799, 309814, 309815, 309832, 
                                                                                                                                                                        309847, 309849, 309865, 309880, 309882, 309899, 309914, 309915, 
                                                                                                                                                                        309932, 309947, 309949, 309965, 309980, 309982, 309999, 369505, 
                                                                                                                                                                        369517, 369519, 369522, 369535, 369538, 369551, 369552, 369555, 
                                                                                                                                                                        369569, 369572, 369584, 369585, 369588, 369602, 369605, 369617, 
                                                                                                                                                                        369619, 369622, 369635, 369638, 369650, 369651, 369652, 369655, 
                                                                                                                                                                        369669, 369672, 369683, 369684, 369685, 369688, 369702, 369705, 
                                                                                                                                                                        369716, 369717, 369719, 369722, 369735, 369738, 369751, 369752, 
                                                                                                                                                                        369755, 369769, 369772, 369784, 369785, 369788, 369802, 369805, 
                                                                                                                                                                        369817, 369819, 369822, 369835, 369838, 369850, 369851, 369852, 
                                                                                                                                                                        369855, 369869, 369872, 369883, 369884, 369885, 369888, 369902, 
                                                                                                                                                                        369905, 369917, 369919, 369922, 369935, 369938, 369951, 369952, 
                                                                                                                                                                        369955, 369969, 369972, 369984, 369985, 369988), File = c("F01", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "F16", "F16")), row.names = c(NA, -183L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `by 
Columns by which to join the two tables. If provided, this must be two columns: start of interval, then end of interval`

Comment: I might be wrong but I think it's just that you've gotten end time and start time the wrong way around